# Huawei E303 Modem change default IP

Tags: windows, ip, modem, huawei-mobile-services

I am trying to use more than one Huawei E303 modem on the same computer.
However, it appears that the modem starts with the default IP 192.168.1.1, so when more than one modem is inserted, they conflict.

Is there any way to change the default IP of this modem?

Answer (score 1):

I thank everyone,
I apologize the question was irrelevant to others.

I did a search and some debugging on the system, on Windows when the modem is inserted, there is a | Huawei service that does the assembly of the modem and the creation of a network interface.

However this service always mounts the modem with ip 192.168.1.1, no matter how many are inserted, not offering modification option.

In summary, without modifying the service code it is not possible to define an ip for each modem.

To solve this problem I will exit Windows and create a solution with Linux using PPP connections.

Thank you